# .load to reload a div with file.php

Tags: php, load

What's the way to reload a div with a php file.  I have a div defined like this in the HTML page.

HTML

```
<div id="tnav"
   <?php require("loadtree.php"); ?>
</div>
```

I have a PHP file that peforms database actions then calls the load method on the div to reload.

```
<?php
 . 
 .
 .
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $('#tnav').load('loadtree.php'); </script>";
?>
```

The script echoes in the source, but this does not cause the page to reload.  What could be the problem?

Comment: are you using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)?  Start by checking that the `load` call is actually getting sent, then check the status of the data that's sent back from the server.  It's possible that the server is returning some kind of error, in which case #tnav won't be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing something similar and I needed to have multiple divs on one page with GET variables passed to the included divs, then I needed to reload each individual div separately with jQuery when a trigger was fired (closing a colorbox in this instance, after an image upload). If it is of any help to anyone, this is how I did it:

In the main script I declared multiple divs, each with a unique id generated by the construction loop:

```
for($i=1;$i<$filecount+1;$i++)
{
?>            
    <div class="someclass" style="width:100%">
        <div id="imgdiv<?php echo $i; ?>">
        </div> 
    </div>
    <?php
    //assign a colorbox link to each to trigger colorbox to open that specific instance (and thus fire that specific trigger when closed) - class="iframe[#]" is used by colorbox to fire. ?> 
    <a class="iframe<?php echo $i; ?>" href="add-new-img.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&imgno=<?php echo $i; ?>">Edit Image <?php echo $i; ?></a>
}
```

Next I used another loop to initialise the JS onload events (now this bit I feel could be done more efficiently than using 10 single onload events..):

```
<script>                
window.onload = function(){
   <?php
   for($i=1;$i<11;$i++)
   {
    ?>
    $("#imgdiv<?php echo $i; ?>").load('php/show-img.php?id=<?php echo $i; ?>&name=<?php echo $name; ?>');      
    <?php
   }
   ?>
}
</script>
```

Finally I wanted each div to reload independently of the others when the relevant trigger was fired. In this case my trigger was a colorbox being closed, so I assigned an instance of colorbox for each of the triggers I needed and tied the onClosed trigger to a function for each div. As each div had a unique name assigned to it I could do this as follows:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  //Assign an individual colorbox instance to each div
  <?php for($i=1;$i<$filecount+1;$i++)
    { ?>
        $(".iframe<?php echo $i; ?>").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"90%", height:"90%", opacity:.8, fixed:true, overlayClose:false, onClosed:function(){$('#imgdiv<?php echo $i; ?>').fadeOut('slow', function(){       
        $("#imgdiv<?php echo $i; ?>").load('php/show-img.php?id=<?php echo $i; ?>&name=<?php echo $name; ?>');          
        $('#imgdiv<?php echo $i; ?>').fadeIn('slow');});
        }});
        <?php
    } ?>        
  });
</script>
```

The function is the same whether encased in the colorbox firing line or not.

I realise this is a huge post and more than you've actually asked for, but I spent weeks looking for a solution like this and couldn't fine one, so hopefully this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed server-side, before the page loads. After the page loads, PHP has no access to the page. You should look into using either JavaScript (or jQuery?) to reload the page, depending on what you are specifically trying to do.

Add a countdown timer in the script output to reload the page using JavaScript.

Comment: PHP outputs this <script> tag into a page that is loaded on the client side.  This is saying that it is sending something back to the page.  The question is why the page is printed but the script tag is kept in the source without being executed?  The script output from PHP is javascript.

Comment: because you should add it to `$(function(){ /* your content */ });`

Comment: made the updates genesis suggested but the div isn't reloaded. I just want to update a tree navigation that is written by loadtree.php. That PHP file gets the tree information from a database, creates a javascript object that has methods to display the treenav.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your contents which should be executed on page load, do it this way

```
$(function(){ 
    /* your content */ 
});
```

so in your case,

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> 
                        $(function(){
                                $('#tnav').load('loadtree.php');
                        }); 
      </script>";
```

Comment: f I update the echo statement as you suggested, the function is shown in the view source but it doesn't reload the div.

Comment: and this code which I given shows in ajax-loaded page or as default page?

Comment: the code shows in the view source for the iframe where I load the php page. The view source for the main page has what was there before the call to the php page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tnav').load('loadtree.php');
    });
</script>";
```

Or, if you want to make your code a little more readable, write the script outside of the php tags so it gets syntax highlighted.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tnav').load('loadtree.php');
    });
</script>
<?php
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to do it either.  The code you suggested does show in the view source for the iframe that loaded the php.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the div to an iframe then reloaded the iframe like this.

```
         $('#tnav').attr('src','loadtreeb.php');
```